# How to pin one itemview in recyclerview that Always show that view on top of recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview. There come data from firebase. I want to pin a item which will be show in top off all item. How can I do this.

I don’t understand how can I do this,

My Adapter Code is

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class ReportAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReportAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<DataReturn> list;

    public ReportAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataReturn> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ReportAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.report_user, parent, false);
        return new ReportAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReportAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DataReturn dataReturn = list.get(position);
        holder.reportId.setText(dataReturn.getFromNumber());
        holder.reportName.setText(dataReturn.getName());
        holder.reportRank.setText(dataReturn.getRank());
        holder.reportLastVacation.setText(dataReturn.getLastVacation());
        holder.reportNextVacation.setText(dataReturn.getComingEnd());
        String image = dataReturn.getImage();
        if (image.equals("")){
            holder.circleImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.error);
        }else {
            Glide.with(context).load(image).into(holder.circleImageView);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private CircleImageView circleImageView;
        TextView reportName, reportLastVacation, reportNextVacation, reportRank,reportId;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            reportId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_number);
            reportName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.report_name);
            reportLastVacation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.report_last_vacation);
            circleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.report_profile_image);
            reportRank = itemView.findViewById(R.id.report_rank);
            reportNextVacation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.next_vacation);

        }
    }
}
```

I don't get any idea how can I do this.
I have the position number which will be show top of the all item.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the onBindViewHolder you can add a onClickListener to the item to and onClick the item would be removed and placed add the 0th index so it appears on the top and notifyDatasetChanged().

```
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Handle the item click here
            // Move the clicked item to the top of the list
            DataReturn clickedItem = list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            list.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            list.add(0, clickedItem);

            // Notify the adapter that the data has changed
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

And you can add a small pin icon as an Imageview in the item view file which would be invisible otherwise and only becomes visible when the user clicks on an item.

Comment: brother thank. Your idea is worked. But I change some little. I added this code where I called data. `Object clickedItem = list.get(12);
                                            list.remove(12);
                                            list.add(0, clickedItem); `